# is t-sne the right way to visualise lsi or lda clusters?

Tags: python, visualization, lda

i am trying to visualise my lsi (latent semantic indexing)clusters with t-sne the problem is that i wanted 3 clusters but in the visualisation am only getting 2, (my data is short text)

[image: visualisation]

```
for i in enumerate(lsimodel[doc_term_matrix2]):
 try:
        p=i[1]       
        p1=p[0]
        p01=p1[1]    
        p2=p[1]
        p02=p2[1]  
        p3=p[2]
        p03=p3[1]
        d=[p01,p02,p03]
        topic_weights.append(d)
 except IndexError:
     pass   
 arr = pd.DataFrame(topic_weights).fillna(0).values 
 topic_num = np.argmax(arr, axis=1)  
 tsne_model = TSNE(n_components=3, verbose=1, random_state=0, angle=.99, 
 init='pca')
 tsne_lsi = tsne_model.fit_transform(arr) 
 output_notebook()
 n_topics =3
 mycolors = np.array([color for name, color in 
 mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS.items()])
 plot = figure(title="t-SNE Clustering of {} LSI Topics".format(n_topics), 
          plot_width=900, plot_height=700)
 plot.scatter(x=tsne_lsi[:,0], y=tsne_lsi[:,1], color=mycolors[topic_num])      
 output_file("foo.html")
```

Comment: Can you post what you are getting out of t-SNE? See the help when you're editing for how to post images.

Comment: It would also help if you could tell us what data you're using too.

Comment: (1) I can see 4 clusters. (2) I do not know where your t-SNE is coming from, but it is usually useful to play around with perplexity, see e.g. the demos [here](https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/).